# MS Access linked Sharepoint list updates not visible during debug

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, vba

I am running some VBA code against an MS Access 2010 DB that is linked to a Sharepoint list.  The code loops thru record sets and updates a specific column given some conditions.

While running this against the DB when it is a copy/not-linked to the live sharepoint list, when I step thru using debug I can see the DB fields get updated without needing to complete the program or exit debug.  However when running in linked mode I can't see the updates to the row/column when stepping thru with debug.

Is this expected behavior? Is there anyway to force and see the updates? I would just like to be certain this behaves correctly before running 1k+ updates.  Below is a sample of basically what I'm doing.  Basically even when I've stepped to the next rst, I can't see the updates to "Notes Field" in the MS Access Table for the previous rst records.

```
Sub ListAttachments()
   Dim dbs As DAO.Database
   Dim rst As DAO.Recordset2
   Dim rsA As DAO.Recordset2
   Dim fld As DAO.Field2

   'Get the database, recordset, and attachment field
   Set dbs = CurrentDb
   Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("tblAttachments")
   Set fld = rst("Attachments")

   'Navigate through the table
   Do While Not rst.EOF

       'Get the recordset for the Attachments field
       Set rsA = fld.Value

       'Print all attachments in the field
       Do While Not rsA.EOF
           Debug.Print , rsA("FileType"), rsA("FileName")

           rst.Edit
           ' Just and example I'm not actually put text below in
           rst("Notes Field") = "This record has one or more attachments"
           rst.Update

           'Next attachment
           rsA.MoveNext
       Loop

       rsA.Close

       'Next record
       rst.MoveNext
    Loop


   rst.Close
   dbs.Close

   Set fld = Nothing
   Set rsA = Nothing
   Set rst = Nothing
   Set dbs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: How long does this code take to run? You want it to update `rst` with new data during processing?

Comment: It takes about 15 minutes to run, I don't need for it to update the rst record each time but I'm fine with it if it does so, this tool will be a use once and throw away tool so I'm not too concerned with the performance.